# Determine if a generic type has a corresponding implementation

Tags: c#, generics

I have a series of static methods to modify a collection then return the modified collection:

```
private static IEnumerable<Invoice> ResolveProxies(IEnumerable<Invoice> e) {
    // do something to e
    return e;
}

private static IEnumerable<Person> ResolveProxies(IEnumerable<Person> e) {
    // do something to e
    return e;
}
```

In another part of the application there is a method to decide if a collection is of a certain type, so that it can be converted to that type and have its corresponding `ResolveProxies` method called:

```
public static GridModel<T> ToGridModel<T>(this GridModel gridModel) {
    // gridModel.Data is just IEnumerable
    var collection = gridModel.Data as IEnumerable<T> ?? new List<T>();

    return new GridModel<T> {
        Data = EvaluateDynamicProxies(collection),
        Total = gridModel.Total
    };
}

private static IEnumerable<T> EvaluateProxies<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
    if (collection is IEnumerable<Invoice>) {
        var enumeration = (collection as IEnumerable<Invoice>);
        return ResolveProxies(enumeration) as IEnumerable<T>;
    }
    if (collection is IEnumerable<Person>) {
        var enumeration = (collection as IEnumerable<Person>);
        return ResolveProxies(enumeration) as IEnumerable<T>;
    }

    // proxy resolution isn't needed so return the unchanged collection
    return collection;
}
```

Having such repetitive conditional logic is bad code smell.  I'm struggling to come up with some way to mark particular types so that I know they have a corresponding proxy resolver method.  Something like this perhaps:

```
public interface IProxyResolver<out T> where T:IEnumerable<T> {
    T ResolveProxies();
}
```

But how would I use this? In effect I need a way to ask the compiler:

1. Does `T` have a matching `ResolveProxies` method?
2. What is the name of the class or method that resolves proxies for `T` so that I can get an instance of it and call it?

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't put the proxy in the class itself, the classes could impliment an interface, or abstract class, that specified to impliment an IProxyResolver?

Comment: @Lloyd The classes (`Invoice`, `Person`, etc.) are part of a POCO project that another team member maintains. We have considered taking that approach but it really takes away from the purity of the POCOs.

Comment: Did you look at attributes, using an attribute to define which IProxyResolver class handles what classes, use reflection in a static class to iterate through the IProxyResolver namespace and build a Key/Value collection of Types/SpecificProxyResolver they use a lookup by type to get the resolver to return? The overhead is then only on the initial static initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inversion of control (IOC) framework.  For example, my team uses [Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx).  You can register services (usually interfaces) and types that provide the services.  It has some nice generics resolution, so you can do things like this:

```
interface IProxyResolver<T> { /* whatever */ }
class ProxyResolver<T> : IProxyResolver<T> { /* ... */ }
class PersonProxyResolver : ProxyResolver<Person> { }
class InvoiceProxyResolver : ProxyResolver<Invoice> { }
```

then, you can summon these types like this:

```
void SomeMethodThatNeedsAProxyResolver<T>(T obj)
{
    var resolver = ioc.Resolve<IProxyResolver<T>>();
    //...
}
```

If you've regsitered the classes above, when T is `Person` or `Invoice`, you get the correct non-generic subclass of ProxyResolver; if it is any other type, you get the default generic superclass.  Of course, you can structure things differently; if you need a specific proxy resolver for every type, that's possible too.

Comment: Yep, that's a little more elegant that the list of conditionals but arguably the same idea. +1 in any case

Comment: IoC is probably the best fit for this problem, but in my case I can't justify adding a dependency on a DI framework just for this one code section (the rest of the project has no need for IoC).

Answer (score 1):

How about using a custom attribute?  This is how custom serializers are selected, etc.

You'd start by defining the Attribute class:

```
public class ProxyResolverAttribute : Attribute {
    public Type ResolverType { get; set; }
    public ProxyResolver(Type resolverType) { ResolverType = resolverType; }
}
```

and then put that on the type contained, e.g.

```
[ProxyResolver(TypeOf(InvoiceProxyResolver))]
public class Invoice ... { ... }
```

then use reflection to see if the generic type used in the collection specifies a proxy resolver type:

```
// Untested, beware of bugs
var enumerationGenericType = enumeration.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
var resolverAttribute = enumerationGenericType.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(TypeOf(ProxyResolverAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();

if (resolverAttribute != null) {
    var resolverType = resolverAttribute.ResolverType;
    // instanciate something of resolverType here
}
```

EDIT: Reading the comments, if you don't want to apply the attributes to the contained objects, I'd suggest creating custom classes which inherit List and apply the attribute there, e.g.

```
[ProxyResolver(TypeOf(InvoiceProxyResolver))]
public class InvoiceList : List<Invoice>
```

Comment: I'll have a look at this tomorrow. Thanks for the input.